# python: Noiseless 3-D rotation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mesh, voxel

**Background:**

Use case: I want to construct a 3-D mesh of a human body from a few pictures.
  More specifically, right now I'm trying to rotate a 3-D numpy array so I can apply the next "mask" of the human body, so I can get a voxel representation of the skin, from which can make the mesh
  Most specifically, the problem is that `scipy.ndimage.rotate()` doesn't do what I need it to for 3 dimensions (though it works great for 2 dimensions).  It also fails for arbitrary rotation angles (ie. 72.9 degrees instead of 90.0 degrees).  It either leaves "off" voxels where there ought to be "on" voxels or (if I use continuous numbers instead of booleans) it leaves a LOT of "on" voxels where there oughta be off voxels.  Is there a better `rotate()` function that solves this noise problem?

**Version info:**

Version specifics:
    python                    2.7.15:          Anaconda, Inc.
    numpy                     1.11.3           py27h3dfced4_4
    numpy-base                1.14.5           py27hdbf6ddf_4
    scipy                     1.1.0            py27hc49cb51_0
    output of `uname -a` :
      Linux elon-eats-my-shorts 4.15.0-42-generic #45~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 19 13:02:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Code:**

```
#====================================================

def rot8(model, angle):
  xy=(1,0); return uint_mids(   scipy.ndimage.rotate(model, angle, axes=xy, reshape=False, mode='constant'))

#====================================================

def uint_mids(arr):
  # NOTE:  do we want this to run on floats?  TODO:   try multiple ways (first on uint8, then float, etc.)
  UINT8_MAX=np.iinfo('uint8').max; MID=int(round(UINT8_MAX/2.))
  arr[np.greater(arr, 0)]=MID; return arr

#====================================================
```

**Results:**

I expect these plt.show() results to look like a 2 dimensional view of a human body with minimal noise.  Instead I either get A) holes inside the human body or B) "body" outside where it should be:

A)

[image: too many "off" voxels]

B)

[image: too many "on" voxels]

For a minimal example of how `scipy.ndimage.rotate()` is imprecise, please play around with code at [this link](https://gist.github.com/neonb88/dbdab1d05f735ae4bc38b6a1e09bbb84).  re: John

*Before* rotation:
[image: 8 voxels]

*After* rotation:
[image: 18 voxels?]

The `rotate()` method created new voxels!  I'm looking for a `rotate_in_3D()` method that doesn't do this

Comment: Your images are broken.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm in the process of fixing.  Thanks for letting me know you can't see them either

Comment: The images are your outputs but what does model look like?

Comment: @John it's hard to render voxels in a program to show you this.  I haven't made this part of the software yet.  The point is that rotating 90 degrees after masking leaves these types of noise, which is undesirable

Comment: Right, but without seeing the thing that you're trying to rotate it's difficult to determine the source of the error.  Could you perhaps make a very low resolution minimal example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @John My apologies.  How's this?

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: NOTE:  I have fixed this problem.  Please contact me via notifications if you would like the solution; it seems not very many people are actually solving this problem except perhaps @John.  If there's more interest, I will post a solution

Comment: @Torvalds_for_president You should post the solution anyway. It's possible someone else has the same issue months or years from now, and you either don't remember your solution or you don't have access to your account anymore. Also, comments are subject to pruning without notification, so they may never see your comment in the first place

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a series of 2D images of a 3D shape taken from different directions and you're trying to recreate the 3D outline of the shape.

Would an algorithm like this accomplish what you're looking to accomplish (pseudo-code)?

```
Initialize all of your voxels to 1
for (mask,angle) in zip(images,directions):
    for pixel in mask:
        if pixel_value < threshold:
            # Nothing there
            draw line along angle offset by pixel location
            set value of every voxel intersected by this line to 0
```

I'm basically thinking that it might be simpler to rotate the 2D images rather than rotate the 3D model.

You could probably come up with a quick-and-dirty implementation pretty fast and that should work for convex objects.  You could probably also do fancier things to smooth the edges.

Comment: so for the masking part, I have a beautifully simple function where I just `np.logical_and()` copies of the mask and the previous model.  But I don't think that works if I rotate the masks?  I'd have to give it some thought

Comment: You could create a second voxel data structure to use as a mask and use np.logical_and() zero out the model but I think that would likely wind up being less efficient than modifying the existing model in place...  It does seem like there should be a more efficient way to create the mask though.  If performance isn't a huge deal, it doesn't hurt to brute force it though.

Comment: I found this summary of different algorithms (no implementation details) http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~seitz/course/Sigg00/slides/seitz-voxel.pdf  Might be useful.

Comment: part of the problem is that I know how to program a noiseless rotation with for loops, but it's slow and would take a lot of debugging.  I'm really looking for a module in any language that is already optimized.  If I have to convert my `np` arrays into C++, that's fine with me, as long as it gets done fast.  I looked at what you posted, though, and it seems like there might be some promising ways to speed up my implementation should I decide to implement it myself

Comment: Have you looked into parallelism?  This seems like the sort of task that would parallelize really readily and if you have access to the computing power you might see better performance from a "unoptimized" parallel implementation than from an optimized serial or lightly threaded implementation.  Worth considering anyway.

Comment: it's definitely worth considering.  I'm guessing that's how `numpy` is so much faster than much of python.  Unfortunately I don't understand threading at the moment.  After I feel content that I've scoured all existing implementations, I'll read up on multithreading.  I'm gonna go ahead and leave your answer an upvote since you've been helpful in conversation and it seems this question is dead, at least until I put a bounty on it